# Jquery.validate - one Page - multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using two form with 2 different submit.Now when i submit that using jquery.validate plugin , the forms are not being able to distinguish.Each form has to post values to a different page.Now what happens is that when clicking submit it is posting values to both the pages.Is there a way to distinguish the forms? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the code of the forms. You must be doing something wrong there.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have to instantiate (ie, `.validate()`) each form individually rather than how you'd expect. Ie, instead of doing:

`$('.mini_form').validate();`

You need to do:

```
$(".mini_form").each(function() {
    $(this).validate();
});
```

I can't take credit for discovering this. 
http://www.epalla.com/2009/12/jquery-validation-with-multiple-forms/

Answer (score 0):

It should be something along these lines

HTML

```
<form action="something-else" method="post" id="form-two">
    <!-- form fields --->
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#form-one').validate({
        //your form fields and rules for #form-one
    });

    $('#form-two').validate({
        //your form fields and rules for #form-two
    });

});
```